# Set terminal size permanently

Tags: command-line

I click in terminal: terminal->132x43 to change terminal size but after each reboot terminal size is set to default setting and I have to change it again. How to set it permanently?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should go to *Edit*->*Profile Preferences*, *General* page and check *Use custom default terminal size*, and then set your preferred horizontal and vertical dimensions.

Answer (score 24):

### Ubuntu 16.04 and later

In Ubuntu 16.04 open the terminal, select *Edit*->*Profile Preferences* -> *General* tab and change the values for columns and rows after where it says *Initial terminal size:*.

[image: IMG:]
  <sup>**16.04**</sup>

In Ubuntu 17.10 and later open the terminal, select *Edit*->*Preferences* -> *Default* profile -> *Text* tab and change the values for columns and rows after where it says *Initial terminal size:*.

[image: IMG:]
  <sup>**17.10 and later**</sup>

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, the dialog layout differs slightly. Upon entering the Preferences dialog, `Unnamed` appears in the left-hand column, under `Profiles`, and selecting it yields a view similar to that pictured in the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Press Ctrl + Alt + t to open a terminal. Make sure the terminal is maximized (if it isn't already) by clicking on the right-most icon at the top of the window (the square in the circle). At the top of the window you should go to Edit -> Profile Preferences, General page and check Use custom default terminal size, and then set your preferred horizontal and vertical dimensions. If you would like unlimited scrolling, go to the Scrolling tab and put a check in the Unlimited box. Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the benefit of ensuring that the terminal window is maximized prior to setting the custom default terminal size? From what I'm able to determine, the terminal's current size has no effect on the `Initial terminal size` values.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions you can find this setting in the `/usr/share/vte/termcap/xterm` file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little script to really permanently set a window size, regardless of gnome-terminal profile that you are currently using. This works on all windows belonging to gnome-terminal

To make it work, you need two things: 1) make sure you have `wmctrl` installed and 2) run this script as one of the Startup Applications.

Notice that line with `wmctrl -i -r $WMCTRL_ID -e 0,0,0,650,650` sets size *and* position according to gravity,x-position,y-position,width,height format

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# date: Sat, Sept 19,2015
# Purpose: a script to permanently set
# terminal window, size
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/64652/295286

APP_CLASS="gnome-terminal.Gnome-terminal"

while [ 1 ]; do
  WIN_ID=$(printf %x $(xdotool getactivewindow))
  WM_CLASS=$(wmctrl -lx | awk -v search=$WIN_ID '{ if($1~search) print $3 }')
  WMCTRL_ID=$( wmctrl -lx | awk -v search2=$WIN_ID '$0~search2 {print $1}' )
    if [ $WM_CLASS = $APP_CLASS ]; then
           wmctrl -i -r $WMCTRL_ID -e 0,0,0,650,650 
    fi
sleep 0.25
done
```

Answer (score 0):

#### `Linux Mint 19.1 (Xfce)`

1. Open Linux Mint Menu button
2. Select `Settings`
3. Select `Xfce Terminal`
4. Navigate the new `Terminal preferences` window to the `Appearance` Tab.
5. Set the *Default Geometry*, to your preference.
6. Close and Enjoy.

---

However, the user config file is located in:
**`~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc`**
and the config item you need (for Xfce) is:
`MiscDefaultGeometry`.

But you can edit faster from the command line with:

```
sed -E 's/MiscDefaultGeometry=.+$/MiscDefaultGeometry=140x40/' -i ~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc
```

Where we have set the size to `140x40` as an example.

Comment: For those down-voting, please provide an explanation out of common courtesy.