# Setting default window size in Ubuntu 16.04 terminal

Tags: 16.04, command-line, window

How can I permanently set a window size in Ubuntu 16.04? I tried to go to *Edit* -> *Edit Preferences* and was able to change the text font and size but not the window size. However, under *Terminal* I could select `132x43` option, but I can't find a way to make it persistent across sessions, in other words the next time I open the terminal I get the small size again.

I tried to do what [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/64657/185480) says, but judging by the date, it must have been several versions ago and the terminal application has changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 open the terminal, select *Edit*->*Profile Preferences*, *General* tab and change the values for columns and rows after where it says *Initial terminal size:*.

[image: IMG:]